# End user machine Cannot find System.Data.SQLite

Tags: linqpad, system.data.sqlite

Linqpad v4.26

This process works great on my Dev box.  I hand copied to the end-user  install folder linqpad.exe, linqpad.exe.config, custom.dll, system.data.sqlite.dll and system.data.sqlite.linq.dll.

I create a connection, click radio button Use a typed data context form your own assembly.  Select Entity Framework, Select Next, Browse to my custom dll.  Choose Provider radio button to other.  System.Data.SQLite is not in the drop down.

I ran the sqlite setup-bundle installer on my Dev box in order to get sqlite installed in the GAC to support VS2010 designer.

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dropdown that shows database providers is populated with `System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactoryClasses()`. If SQLite is not listed, then it hasn't been registered in the machine.config. However, LINQPad doesn't stop you from entering the name of the provider manually, as you would in constructing an Entity Framework connection string.

Comment: That must explain why I have to put this in my app.config class also: <system.data><DbProviderFactories><remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite"/><add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite"/></DBProviderFactories>

Comment: spoke too soon...when I add the above to the linqpad.exe.config file I see System.Data.SQLite in the dropdown but when select the Test button linqpad says I have a valid connection with an inner exception of The specified store provider cannot be found in the configuration, or is not valid.

Comment: Try also adding that to a file called linqpad.config - this is the config for your queries rather than LINQPad itself.

Comment: I get Exception has been thrown by a target of an invocation.  I then removed the System.dat.sqlite.dll files that were in the current directory and reran the sqlite setup installer.  I verified <DbProviderFactories> sections, note that is has PublicKeyToken attribute.  I tried Linqpad with and without <DBProviderFactories> in the linqpad.config file.  Each time I get popup Failed to find or load the registered .NET Framework data provider.  I'm about to retry the SQLite installation using the "setup-bundle" vice just setup.  The bundle includes VS2010 design time support and is for Dev only

Comment: BTW, on my Windows 7 x64 dev box, Linqpad automatically sniffs out the connection string for me after a small delay.  On the customer XP machine it never displays it, I assume cuz of any of the above problems.

Comment: Runing the sqlite-netFx40-setup-bundle-x86-2010-1.0.82.0.exe allowed me to select a checkbox "Install in Global Assembly Cache" GAC.  It works!!  You do need to have the DBFactory section in the linqpad.config otherwise you get the popup, "The database connection is valid...etc"  Funny how I don't need that file on my Dev box either.  Wish I knew why the non-GAC install does not work.

Answer (score 0):

+1, because even though I can see it in the drop down it doesn't appear to be valid.

I have now done the following to no avail:

1. Ran sqlite-netFx40-Setup-x86-2010-1.0.82.0.exe on the client machine.
2. Copy/pasted from the readme.htm  sections into the Linqpad.exe.config file.
3. Copied the System.Data.SQLite.dlls from Program Files\System.data.sqlite to the app dir where I installed Linqpad.
4. Fired up linqpad selected my custom provider.  It shows all of the tables but as soon as I try and run any query I get exceptions.